# Fat Controllerを解消する為にFormから送られてきたデータの加工処理をどこか別のところに移したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsを使っています。
Formから送られてくるデータをControllerで加工していたらControllerがFatになってきました。
Fat Controllerを解消する為にもどこか別のところに処理を移したいと思っています。

加工内容の例：

- 入力値から関連するモデルを特定しそのIDを付加する
- date_selectで送られてくる日付情報を元にその日の最終日時を取得し置き換える

などです。

何となく[apotonick/reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform)等のForm Objectを使うのが良さそうな気はしているのですが、どこに移動させるのが適切でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

もし「コントローラが肥大化したのでそれを**まとめて**どこかに移す」という発想をしているのであれば、肥大化した「何か」が別に出来るだけでなんの解決にもなりません。

たとえば[7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)という記事にはFat Modelを解消する手法が7つ紹介されていますが、7つもあるというのはつまり「Fat Modelを解消するたった一つの適切な方法」なるものが存在しないことを意味しています。Controllerでも同じことです。

ということで、適切な移動先は個々の処理それぞれで検討する必要があります。実際の処理と関連するビューやモデルの構造が具体的に提示できれば個別に検討できるかもしれませんが、

> - 入力値から関連するモデルを特定しそのIDを付加する
> - date_selectで送られてくる日付情報を元にその日の最終日時を取得し置き換える

これだとビジネスロジックなのかそうでないかも判然としないので、なんとも言いようがありません。

また、モデルに移動できないロジックがコントローラにあるということだと、そもそもアプリケーションの構造を見直すべきかもしれません。モデルやビューの構造が不適切であるためにコントローラがその仲介をしている結果としてコントローラが肥大化している場合はそれを直さないと「余計な」処理は解消できません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

Fat Controllerを解消するたった1つの適切な方法を知りたいわけではなかったですし、まとめて移したいという話でもなかったです。

Fat Controllerになっている原因の1つとして、Formから送られてくるデータの加工処理というものがあり、それを該当Controller外に移動させるとしてどこに移動させるのが適切かという内容でした。

それをModelへ移動するという手もあると思いますが、それをしてしまうと今度は逆にFat Modelになると思っていて、Form Objectが良さそうだと思っているという内容の投稿をしました。

質問に色々と不備があり申し訳ありません。
この内容で改めてご回答頂けるようでしたら幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

これが正解！というのはなかなか見つからず悩ましいですよね。
私の場合は、

他のControllerでもよく使うような処理であれば、Concernsに切り出してます。
http://elegantbrew.tumblr.com/post/70990048275/controller-concerns-in-rails-4

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます！
他のControllerでも使うような処理だとConcernに切り出すのは分かります。
もしConcernに切り出すほど他のControllerからは使われないような場合はどうされますか？

Comment: あまり良くないのかなーと思いつつ、可読性のためだけにConcenに切りだしちゃってたりします。

Comment: なるほど！それも手かもしれませんね

Comment: こういう問題はプロジェクト毎で単一の答えも無いし悩ましいですよね。僕も他のチームの答えが知りたいです。concernでなんとかしちゃう方法は最適解じゃない気がしますが、Rails4標準の知識範囲でできるので妥協点としてはアリかなと思って使ってます。